# Java Graph Library Support DOT format

Tags: java, graph, dot

I am looking for a java library similar to JUNG (http://jung.sourceforge.net/), but support DOT language.
Grappa which built on top of GraphViz support DOT, but it requires GraphViz binary.
Pure java library would be easier for distributing my program.

Comment: I think Webdot solves my problem, but I am still curious if there is any java library existing?